# Matlab: Calculate intersection point of vector and analytical surface

Tags: matlab, vector, iteration, intersection, surface

I would like to compute the intersection point in R^3 of a vector given by
     p + alpha * n   where x is a spatial vector, n is another vector and alpha is a scalar to be determined.

the surface is given in analytical form by the formulation

f(x,y) = [x, y, z(x,y)] where z(x,y) can be an arbitrary nonlinear surface description

I set up a linearization:

```
 [n1 n2   n3        ] (d_alpha)= [p1 + alpha*n1 - x]
 [-1  0  -dz(x,y)/dx] (d_x)    = [p2 + alpha*n2 - y]
 [ 0 -1  -dz(x,y)/dx] (d_y)    = [p3 + alpha*n3 - z(x,y)]
```

and search to iterate with starting values for alpha, x and y

However, I cant seem to converge here. Any idea where my mistake is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A vector does not intersect it does not have a position, it only has a magnitude and a direction. Do you mean that you have a line that intersects a plane or that you want to project the vector on the plane?

Comment: I mean intersection with the line emanating from p in the direction of n

Comment: Is it possible for the line to intersect the plane for more than once?

Comment: no that is assumed to be excluded

Comment: The guess it that you can parameterize the line and solve it according to [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-vectors-and-matrices/part-c-parametric-equations-for-curves/session-16-intersection-of-a-line-and-a-plane/MIT18_02SC_we_9_comb.pdf). You should be able to solve the equation with any matlab equation solver (eg `fzero` or `solve`). Another thing that comes to my mind is to rotate and translate the surface so that the line goes along some axis (eg x-axis) or so. That will give you a function where the other variables are 0.

Comment: You may get even better help if you submit an example surface, though rotating a shape to align ray/line along some line should be a fairly cheap way to do it. That is also what some ray-tracing algorithms do. They translate an object and shoot a ray from origo, in the direction of some axis. The if the ray passes a wall, you have a collision and if it passes an odd number of walls, you are inside an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your equations as

```
x_line(a) = p1 + a * n1
y_line(a) = p2 + a * n2 
z_line(a) = p3 + a * n3
z_plane(x, y) = fun(x, y)
```

Assuming that your problem has a unique solution, the height along the z-direction `dz` of the line above the plane, as a function of `a` is then

```
dz(a) = z_line(a) - fun(x_line(a), y_line(a))
      = p3 + a * n3 - fun(p1 + a * n1, p2 + a * n2)
```

To find the intersection of the line with the plane, you simply have to find the value of `a` for which `dz` is zero. This can be done in Matlab using an [anonymous function](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) and [fzero](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) like so:

```
dz = @(a) = p3 + a * n3 - fun(p1 + a * n1, p2 + a * n2);
a_intersect = fzero(dz, a0);
```

where `a0` is some (arbitrary) starting guess for `a`.
You might want read a bit about optical ray-tracing, I guess you might find some introductory university notes online. This is a pretty standard problem for finding e.g. the intersection of an optical ray and a curved lens or a parabolic mirror.

Comment: thank you for your effort. I tried to implement it like this:                                      p = [1;1;1];
n = [0;0;-1];
dz = @(a) p(3) + a * n(3) - test_projsurf([p(1) + a * n(1), (2) + a * n(2)]);

a_intersect = fzero(dz, 0.01)